# Bypass capacitor pad in series or in parallel with load?

Tags: pcb, layout, bypass-capacitor

I have been skimming through various good bypass cap layouts and cannot tell if this makes any difference:

[image]

On the first case, I would have a load and the bypass cap's VCC pad connected from different traces starting from the power lines, so technically there is no current on the trace leading to the bypass cap

[image]

On the second case, I would have the load and the bypass cap's VCC pad connected with a single trace on the PCB.

Is there any preferred layout? (Is it something to avoid to have current running through a bypass cap's pad?)

Comment: Both of these are parallel.

Comment: In bypass, the GND is every bit as important as the VCC. If possible, keep the GND pad close to the GND pin. Run a trace from the pad to the pin.

Comment: @mkeith I agree, yet In this example I really wanted to isolate the single parameter of having the bypass on the load's trace or on a different trace (given there is no power plane). On the imgs above, there would be a ground plane, although not illustrated.

Comment: @Hearth You are right, I edited :S

Comment: There IS current on the VCC trace in the first example.   The high-frequency AC noise being bypassed is traveling "through" that capacitor.   Anyhow, #2 is generally considered "best".  This arrangement minimizes AC currents that may flow back to the source (keeps EMI noise down, keeping the FCC test engineers happy)   That little bit of extra trace is an inductance, which reduces the caps effectiveness.  You also want the minimum possible open loop area there, keeps the capacitors impedance low as possible.